# Read from file a number and after that an array in C

Tags: c

How can I read from a file a number and after an array. i mean my file looks like that:
3
7
8
9

3 is the number of components, 7, 8 9 the other components of the array, arr[1], arr[2], arr[3].

Comment: please read `man 3 fscanf` first...

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: If you are on a *nix computer just type man 3 fscanf in terminal. Otherwise you can view it [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf)

Comment: you mean `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]`, in C in  index starts at 0, not 1. So `fopen`, a loop doing `fscanf`, then `fclose` and what about an other loop doing `printf` to check the result ?

Comment: @ANA https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm    just google it before you post, basically you read first number create array in the same size create for loop to keep reading all of the numbers and adding it in the array make sure to close file after work is done.

Comment: @dt170 i understood, but how can i do for starting to read the number after, like to start to read the array with the second value from file after the number of components

Comment: @ANA you keep using `fscanf ` full example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639783/read-from-file-a-number-and-after-that-an-array-in-c?noredirect=1#comment109033790_61639783 if you still having issues I will help you write the proper code for your file .

Answer (score 1):

one way to perform the desired functionality is:

First, open the file for reading:

```
FILE *fp = fopen( "filename.txt" );
```

Then check that the call to `fopen()` was successful and handle any error:

```
if( ! fp )
{
    perror( "fopen to read filename.txt failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Note: `perror()` outputs both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`. which is where error messages should be output.

reserve a variable to hold the count of following values:

```
int maxLoops;
```

then read the first number and use that number as the max iterations of a loop, of course, checking for errors

```
if( fscanf( fp, "%d", &maxLoops ) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "fscanf to read loop count failed\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Note: the `scanf()` family of functions does not set `errno` when some `input format specifier` (in this case `%d`) fails, so need to output an error message using something like `fprinf()`.

Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful `input format conversions` (or EOF)

Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

then, reserve an array for the following entries in the file, using the Variable Array Length feature of C

```
int dataArray[ maxLoops ];
```

Now, set up the loop that will read the rest of the data

```
for( int i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++ )
{
```

for each pass through the loop read another entry into the array, of course, checking for errors

```
    if( fscanf( fp, "%d", &dataArray[i] ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for data value failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}  // end the loop
```

then, cleanup before doing anything else:

```
fclose( fp );
```

What you do with the data is up to you. You might want to print out each of the data values with a loop, similar to:

```
for( int i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++ )
{
    printf( "entry %d = %d\n", i, dataArray[i] );
}
```

Note: when calling `printf()` no need to obtain the address of a variable (unless that is what you want to print).  However, when inputting a variable, as when calling `fscanf()` need the address of the variable.